# I can't type § in minecraft for some reason

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I try typing Alt+Numpad1Numpad2 (that's §) and  nothing happens and it wont copy and paste it ether
I'm trying to name a shulker box §2FOOD so it says FOOD in dark green, it already says 'Shulker Box' in dark gray and in the anvil it says '§7 Shulker Box' but when I try to replace the 7 with a 2 it just removes the § in fact when I try to change the name at all it automaticaly gets rid of the § but what i think the weirdest part is that I can add any other symbol such as ☺ ☻ ∞ and ╚ for example please help me because I cant find anything else to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign text color: Can't enter the § symbol](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382064/sign-text-color-cant-enter-the-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Java player, then it won't work. You have to use "&". Example:  "&4 Hi", it will show a different color and the message you wrote and there is even formatting codes.

Here is a photo:

[image: So What Your Seeing Here is The Color Chat Plugin It Can Be Used In Servers!]

If you are using a single player world, then you have to do it by commands/ mods.

Comment: Where did you get this picture from? Did this appear in the chat while playing on a server? I think the software that allows `§` to be replaced by `&` is server-specific.